# taking inputs and printing a large number of integers

Tags: c++, ubuntu

I was testing my code against some 10001 values, but it did not print any output value.

I found out it was not even printing out anything even when I am merely taking inputs using `cin` and printing using `cout` when the value is large(some thousands).

When I ran the same thing in www.ideone.com it worked, but in my own machine it is not printing anything.

The program is:

```
int main() {
    int N, x;
    cin >> N;
    int ar[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cin >> x;
        ar[i] = x;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        cout << ar[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

and the sample input can be downloaded in http://ideone.com/S3EneQ using copy.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and `g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2` (2013).

Comment: I'm sorry, im wrong about some of what i wrote. Entering multiple numbers should count as multiple values for cin. I will remove my comments so they dont spread missinformation. :)

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to tell you why a properly written function that works in ideoone doesn't work on your computer. Have you tried using a debugger to see what's happening when it runs?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a large array on the stack with `int ar[N]` and this is a bad idea.

Replace `int ar[N]` with `std::vector<int> ar(N)`.

By the way dynamically-sized arrays are supported as non-portable extensions because they're not part of the standard C++ language.

Comment: Oh I've also tried using `vector`. It did not work either.

Comment: Show your code with `vector` and explain how it didn't work (ask a new question).